# How to fix blending or depth mode in the model

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, libgdx, shader

I can't figure out the problem, but may be the problem with 
either blending or depth-testing.

The blending function i'm using is

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

These are the output without `glDepthFunc` functions

Getting this as output
[image: Output]

[image]

This should be like this

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Importing-Blender-models-in-LibGDX#troubleshooting-missing-textures

Comment: In addition to drawing everything in the proper order, you also need to turn face culling off for this to work.

Comment: In this particular case, you don't seem to use any _semi-transparent_ parts, just totally opaque and totally transpaernt texels. In that case, you could get away with discarding the transparent fragments (`GL_ALPHA_TEST` in old GL, or a conditional `discard` in the fragment shader on modern GL). However, that apporach will lead to some artifacts at the edges, as the texture filter will prdocue semi-transparent pixels.

Comment: Could you elaborate "it should be transparent but it is showing the glClearColor"? If it is transparent you should be able to see through it which in your case is the background having glClearColor. The image you posted as the expected result seems to have no transparency. So what is your issue and what is the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clear color that shows through is indicative that it draw the stem of the stawberry first, followed by the berry itself. As a rule of thumb, you should render opaque surfaces, before semi-opaque surfaces, the leafs of the stem are semi-opaque (the leafs are not actual polygons). While you draw you have the depth-buffer enabled. This causes fragments of bery to be rejected on the grounds that the 'translucent' fragments of leaf/stem are already drawn (and closer to the camera/view).

Changing the order around is a simple step to stop it from producing the illustrated artifact, because the fragments of the objects with the 'furtest' depth are rendered before the fragments with the 'nearest' depth. In other words, the depth buffer causes the fragments to be accepted, instead of rejected.